# How can i show Multiple pins on the map?

Tags: iphone

i want to show multiple pins on my MapView all with Animation of Dropping pin so how it is possible if any body have sample code then please send send link.i am new in this field.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few code samples on developer.apple.com

[This](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/MapCallouts/Introduction/Intro.html)

is a simple map example with two pins

Comment: Simply call addAnnotations on your MKMapView with an array of all the MKAnnotationViews. 
If you want the drop animation, set animatesDrop to true

Answer (score 0):

Just as you show single pin.. keep the code for single pin in Loop and pass different longitude latitude in loop.. You will get the pins at different location

Answer (score -1):

```
if([points retainCount] > 0)
{
    [points release];
    points = nil;


}


if([annotationAry retainCount] > 0)
{
    [annotationAry release];
    annotationAry = nil;


}
points = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
annotationAry = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; 
for(int i=0;i<[longitudeary count];i++)
{   
    CLLocation* currentLocation1 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[[latitudeary objectAtIndex:i]doubleValue] longitude:[[longitudeary objectAtIndex:i]doubleValue]];

    [points addObject:currentLocation1];
}


for(int i=0;i<[points count];i++)
{



    // CREATE THE ANNOTATIONS AND ADD THEM TO THE MAP
    CSMapAnnotation* annotation = nil;

    // create the start annotation and add it to the array
        annotation = [[[CSMapAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:[[points objectAtIndex:i] coordinate] 
                                             annotationType:CSMapAnnotationTypeImage 
                                                        title:@"123456..."
                                                         shID:[shIDary objectAtIndex:i] 
                                                        catID:[catIDary objectAtIndex:i]
                                                    ciggUse:[ciggaretteUSEary objectAtIndex:i]
                                                    wifiUse:[wifiUSEary objectAtIndex:i]
                                                 controller:self]autorelease];


    [annotationAry addObject:annotation];

}

[mapViewmy addAnnotations:[NSArray arrayWithArray:annotationAry]];
```

Comment: Do not use retainCount, it does not work the way shown! See this answer: [When to use -retainCount?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4636477/451475). Also see: [retainCount is useless](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2011/12/18/retaincount-is-useless/), [When to use -retainCount?](http://sdarlington.github.io) and/or [When to use the retainCount method](http://iosdevelopertips.com/core-services/when-to-use-the-retaincount-method.html).