# When does retain count for an autoreleased object decrement?

Tags: objective-c, retain, autorelease

If I have an autoreleased object, when does its retain count (i.e. the value returned when I call the method retainCount on it) decrement? I had figured it to be when the scope of the method the object was allocated within ended, but my tests aren't indicating that.  I have code like the following:

```
int itemIndex = 0;
NSArray* items = [mResponse componentsSeparatedByString:@","];  
self.mText = (NSString*)[items objectAtIndex:itemIndex++];
self.mText = [mText gtm_stringByUnescapingFromURLArgument];
NSLog(@"retain count: %d",[mText retainCount]);
```

This returns 2 for the count (mText has a retain property so that makes sense), and after exiting this method, the call from outside likewise returns 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Don't look at retainCount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636146/when-to-use-retaincount/4636477#4636477). It's misleading. As long as you follow the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) then you'll be fine.

If you rephrase your question to say "When does the default autorelease pool drain?" then the answer is when control flow returns to the runloop.