# Why is the retainCount still 1 after [object release]?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
NSLog(@"first:%u",[object retainCount]);
[object release];
NSLog(@"second:%u",[object retainCount]);
```

Output:

```
first:1
second:1
```

Why doesn't the object get released?

Comment: Basically don't use retainCpount http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636146/when-to-use-retaincount and many more questions here

Comment: You should never use [`retainCount`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636146/when-to-use-retaincount).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

a Quote from NSObject reference on retainCount method

> This method is typically of no value
>   in debugging memory management issues.
>   Because any number of framework
>   objects may have retained an object in
>   order to hold references to it, while
>   at the same time autorelease pools may
>   be holding any number of deferred
>   releases on an object, it is very
>   unlikely that you can get useful
>   information from this method.

Comment: BIG +1 for the docs quote. The main thing that method does is send developers to SO to ask increasingly insane questions.

Comment: Haha, I love both these comments.

Comment: Except when you have objects that won't dealloc, and you can't run Instruments on them. SO is currently 99% noise, 1% signal on this topic thanks to all the "don't look at retainCount" responses

Answer (score 4):

Object can be released but not when you think it will be. Basically, don't look at retainCount. It may not change until the next runloop or at all, it's an implementation detail. You will get a sense for when you need to release and when you don't with experience but until then rely on the clang analyzer.

Answer (score 1):

First, [`retainCount`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html) doesn't give you a number you can use. It's meaningless.

Second, the reason the retainCount is 0 is *probably* that you try to work with an object *that doesn't exist anymore*. You're lucky your application doesn't crash, because your accessing invalid memory. Decreasing the retainCount just before deallocating an object is unnecessary, therefore Apple doesn't do it, *probably*.

Answer (score 1):

Divide any number by zero and you will find the meaning of "object with retain count of zero".

Answer (score -1):

I agree with the other comments about not using retainCount to get a reliable count.

EDIT: Ignore my stupidity below... :)

<strike>However, I've observed that setting the corresponding property to nil...</strike>

```
self.object = nil;
```

the retainCount does tend to be decremented immediately.

Comment: and how is this supposed to answer the question?

Comment: Answer this and you'll understand the downvote;  How is `foo = nil; [foo retainCount];` any different from `[nil retainCount];` or [0 retainCount];`?

Comment: Doh! I realised my mistake after posting that `self.object = nil;` would end up sending retainCount to a nil object, which obviously returns 0. Too slow with my edit to stop the downvote.