# one alloc, retainCount == 2

Tags: iphone, memory-management

I have a following code:

```
NSLog(@"%d", [chart retainCount]);

self.chart = [[BNPieChart alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
NSLog(@"%d", [chart retainCount]);
```

Terminal shows:

```
[Session started at 2011-03-28 11:09:46 +0200.]
2011-03-28 11:09:51.008 Finance[35111:207] 0

2011-03-28 11:09:51.010 Finance[35111:207] 2
```

As I know, retainCount should be equal to 1, not 2.

Comment: "As I know, retainCount should be equal to 1, not 2." Are you an author of `BNPieChat`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use -retainCount ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636146/when-to-use-retaincount)

Comment: Do not use `-retainCount`, even for debug it is not accurate. See this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636146/when-to-use-retaincount/4636477#4636477

Comment: Does BNPieChart create another object, passing a reference to itself which then gets retained?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You chart property defined as retain or copy, so:

```
self.chart = [[BNPieChart alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
```

+1 retain at alloc (`[BNPieChart alloc]`)
+1 retain at assignment (`self.chart =` )

Comment: ... also demonstrating that you should **always** think of retain counts in terms of deltas.   You only increase/decrease the retain count, never look at the absolute value.  As long as your increase/decrease operations are in balance, your code will not leak.

Answer (score 3):

chart is probably a retained property, that's why you have 2 retainCount. That's why you can see some declaration like that :

```
BNPieChart *aChart = [[BNPieChart alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
self.chart = aChart;
[aChart release];
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to self in the statement its retain count is 2 as property of the chart is declared as `retain` 
Remove self from the statement

change

```
 self.chart = [[BNPieChart alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
```

to

```
 chart = [[BNPieChart alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
```

Comment: Could you explain the difference between self.chart and chart? Thanks!

Comment: self.chart is nothing but the method getchart in Java/C++... so internally self.chart calling method getchart and if property of the chart is "retain" at the the time of assignment the get methord will alloc memory ,increase retain count and returns chart if chart is nil... where if you write simply chart you simply referring class variable chart

Answer (score 0):

How do you know that the retainCount should be 1? Are you the author of the **-setChart:** method you are calling? How is it implemented? Why didn't you include it in the post?

Nothing you have posted here is suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 possible problems I see:

1. When you synthesized the `chart` property, it was synthesized with a `retain` attribute
2. You have called `retain` in a self-implemented getter method
3. Whoever wrote the initializer method for `BNPieChart` or its superclass's designated initializer had a `retain` in the initializer.

Have you seen the code for `BNPieChart` and its non-Cocoa superclasses? If you can, try to post the initializer code.