# when to use retainCount (never, and why)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When to use -retainCount ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636146/when-to-use-retaincount)

when to use retainCount (never, and why)

Answer (score 0):

NSObject retainCount is simply a "what's under the hood" curiosity and possibly debugging aid.  You don't want to care what the actual value is for production.  Code beyond your direct control could be retaining/releasing changing the value.