# Diagnosing error: "release sent to deallocated object"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, cfstring

I received this error message:

```
message [CFString release] sent to deallocated object at 0x........
```

How can I know which string caused this problem? Can I figure out which `CFString` it is using the debugger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using XCode 4, use the Zombie instrument (Build and Profile).  When this message occurs, you can press the arrow to get a list of everywhere the string was retained and released.

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled to put in a breakpoint and look back up the stack to find release statement where it occurred.

Answer (score -1):

At firts, you can try lookup your code for alloc/dealloc functions, and count it.
It's has been as "**count alloc == count dealloc**".
The second step, look for some construction:

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWith...]; // Auto alloc/init with content
[myString release]; // Release before use
NSLog(@"%@", myString); // Use after release
```

Or try debug with `NSLog(%"retain count :%d", [myString retainCount]);`

Comment: Don't debug using retain count. It doesn't tell you anything useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636146/when-to-use-retaincount.

Comment: You also test your program in Instruments, for memory leak and see where you get it :)