# How do i see my variables' reference count?

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-management, instruments

I have a problem with objects not being 'deallocked', does anyone know of a way to see the reference count chart in either Xcode or Instruments? I know how to do this in the leaks template in Instruments, but strangely, Leaks detects nothing. I do think there is a leak though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Instruments says there is no leak, then it surely is right (except if you managed to produce a retain cycle). You can peak at `[obj retainCount]`, but [it is strongly discouraged to do so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784084/calling-retaincount-considered-harmful).

Remember that you can create "leaks" for example by putting stuff into NSMutableArrays or NSMutableDictionaries and never removing them. These kind of leaks won't show up Instruments. Same for [retain cycles](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/rules-to-avoid-retain-cycles.html). So you should look for these problems.