# Retain count issue in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, cocoa, memory-management

I have small doubt about in checking retain count of the object:

Please find the below code, it is displaying retainCount is 1 after releasing the object memory.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        CGRect contentRect = [cell.contentView bounds];     
        UIImageView *thumbView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:IMAGE_CELL_BACKGROUND]];
        thumbView.frame = contentRect;      
        cell.backgroundView=thumbView;
        [thumbView release];
    }
    UIImageView *image=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"left_arrow.png"]];
    **NSLog(@"Image retain count %d",[image retainCount]);**
    image.frame=CGRectMake(290, 12.5, [UIImage imageNamed:@"left_arrow.png"].size.width,  [UIImage imageNamed:@"left_arrow.png"].size.height);
    image.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:image];
    [image release];
    **NSLog(@"Image retain count-- after %d",[image retainCount]);**


        // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: You really shouldn't be relying on the `retainCount` values.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5784084/3009) for more explanation.

Comment: I'll put it more strongly: `retainCount` **is worse than useless.** You cannot trust it to help you in anything, because **it is very likely to lead you down a wrong path and/or confuse you**. Think in terms of ownerships, as prescribed by the Memory Management Programming Guide, and if you *must* look at retains and releases (for debugging purposes only!), use Instruments's Leaks template instead.

Answer (score 6):

This is perfectly normal. `cell.contentView` still holds a reference to the image. When you call `[cell.contenetView addSubview:image]`, `cell.contentView` stores the image reference somewhere (probably in an array or something similar), and it increases the reference counter by 1 to ensure that the `image` is not deallocated while `cell.contentView` is still using it. Whenever `cell.contentView` is deallocated for whatever reason, it will ensure that the retain count of the image is decreased by 1.

Comment: Hi Tamas can you please help me how can i mange memory in this scenario.

Comment: if i say image=nil instead of [image release], will it be good practice, sorry for my poor question. I HAVE TO LEARN MEMORY MANAGEMENT.

Comment: No, because you will be leaking a reference by doing that. (You own a reference to ``image`` because you initialized it with an ``init...`` method, hence you *must* release that reference somewhere where you do not need ``image`` any more).

Comment: @VsN: More specifically, assigning a new value to the `image` variable is not the same as sending a `release` message to the `image` object (more precisely, the object whose pointer is in the `image` variable). Only sending a `release` message releases the object. Sending an `autorelease` message causes the pool to send the object a `release` message later. Assigning to a variable causes a `release` message not at all.

Answer (score 1):

The `addSubview:` call in the line before `[image release]` causes the cell's `contentView` to retain the image view, so it's completely expected that the retain count is 1 after that – it would be pretty bad if it was zero because you (or rather the cell's `contentView`) still need the image view to be in memory.

By releasing it, you've essentially given the `contentView` the sole responsibility of releasing the image view when it is released itself or doesn't need it anymore (e.g. if `removeFromSuperview` is called).