# NSTimer retain count increases, why?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, retaincount

I have a problem regarding `NSTimer`. See the following code:

```
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = 1.0f;
SEL selector = @selector(executeDataRefresh);

NSMethodSignature *methodSignature = [[ExecuteDataRefesh class] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:selector];

NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:methodSignature];
[invocation setTarget:executeDataRefresh];
[invocation setSelector:selector];

NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:  timeInterval invocation:invocation repeats:YES];
```

The object `executeDataRefresh`'s retain count will now increase by 1 each invocation of method `executeDataRefresh`. So after 1 minute the retain count is 60.

I know the method `retainCount` shouldn't be used, but is this method really this "incorrect"?

How come?

Comment: can you add the code of the executeDataRefresh method? I suspect it has something to do with you problem.

Comment: if you know it shouldn't be used, why do you use it?

Comment: edo42: I had problem with memory management so in a desperate try to fix it I started to log the retainCount.. But yeah, you are right, it generated more questions than answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `NSInvocation` retains its target because it needs the target to still be around when the timer fires. That fact is sort of buried in the documentation for [`-[NSInvocation retainArguments]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000212-retainArguments):

> If the receiver hasn’t already done so, retains the target [...]
>   `NSTimer`s always instruct their `NSInvocation`s to retain their arguments, [...] because there’s usually a delay before an `NSTimer` fires.

This is what is meant when someone says "Framework classes may be retaining things without you knowing". [Don't worry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784084/calling-retaincount-considered-harmful) about [absolute retain counts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636146/when-to-use-retaincount/4636477#4636477).

What you should perhaps be worrying about instead* is the fact that, every time you run this code (which you seem to indicate happens fairly often), you are creating a new `NSInvocation` and repeating `NSTimer` instance with exactly the same attributes as the last time, which seems like a waste of memory.

---

*Unless this is just test code.

Comment: I have read about setTarget: in  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html 
It says "The object to assign to the receiver as target. " about the object set to target. The usage of word "assign" is interesting :)

Comment: The use of the word "assign" there isn't likely to have anything to do with the `assign` keyword for declared properties, implying memory management. However, I was misremembering that `NSInvocation` _automatically_ retains its target. It does not, but an `NSTimer` causes it to do so, and I've added a reference to the docs that indicate this.