# Releasing objects: [obj release]; is not enough, need [obj release], obj = nil;?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, null, retaincount

Here I got some ugly code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSString *textWithYear = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"text and year %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date] ];
[dateFormatter release];
NSLog(@"%i", [dateFormatter retainCount]); // returns 1 !
```

As you see, retains counter returns 1, which I suppose means that the object is not released.
If I change that string to

```
[dateFormatter release], dateFromatter = nil;
```

retains counter returns 0, which is supposedly because it can't count retains for nil :)

Is there something that I don't understand about retains counter, or this object is really not released? When I send `release` to it for the second time (striving to get zero retains count) it crushes expectedly :)

And one more question: if the dateFormatter was really released, why doesn't it crash when i call [dateFormatter retainCount] ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correctly releasing your object; don't worry about the retain count.  And don't use `-retainCount`.  See [When to use -retainCount?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636146/when-to-use-retaincount) or [Calling -retainCount Considered Harmful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784084/calling-retaincount-considered-harmful) for more details about why.

Do note that your code here will crash if the object does get destroyed (because the call to `-retainCount` comes after you've released it and may be to a dangling pointer); setting your variables to `nil` after you are done with them is a good habit to protect against this. But it has nothing to do with whether your code is leaking.

Comment: One question: if the `dateFormatter` was really released, why doesn't it crash when i call [dateFormatter retainCount] ?..

Comment: @Seamus you mean "if the object does get deallocated", right? There could be other references keeping it alive.

Comment: @Richard - yes; in fact, other references are clearly keeping this object alive.  Edited, thanks.

Comment: Or it could be coincidence.  Freeing memory doesn't change the contents and, thus, a dangling pointer will appear to continue to work until something does scribble on the memory.

Comment: (Which is why you can't rely on `retainCount` to tell you *anything*.)