# Why does NSNumber wrong count a retaincount?

Tags: objective-c

Here is retaincount code.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        NSNumber *number = [[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:10];
        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:0];

        NSLog(@"retain count : %d",[number retainCount]);

        [array addObject:number];
        NSLog(@"retain count : %d",[number retainCount]);

        [number release];
        NSLog(@"retain count : %d",[number retainCount]);

        [number release];
        NSLog(@"retain count : %d",[number retainCount]);

        [number release];
        NSLog(@"retain count : %d",[number retainCount]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My expected answer is

```
retain count : 1
retain count : 2
retain count : 1
retain count : 0
and then error
```

but actually running result is as following.

```
[Switching to process 6363 thread 0x0]
2011-12-01 19:39:53.843 nsnumber[6363:707] retain count : -1
2011-12-01 19:39:53.846 nsnumber[6363:707] retain count : -1
2011-12-01 19:39:53.847 nsnumber[6363:707] retain count : -1
2011-12-01 19:39:53.847 nsnumber[6363:707] retain count : -1
2011-12-01 19:39:53.848 nsnumber[6363:707] retain count : -1
```

I can't understand this result.

Why is this the result will come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About retainCount

> This method is typically of no value in debugging memory management
>   issues. Because any number of framework objects may have retained an
>   object in order to hold references to it, while at the same time
>   autorelease pools may be holding any number of deferred releases on an
>   object, it is very unlikely that you can get useful information from
>   this method.

See also

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/retainCount

[When to use -retainCount?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636146/when-to-use-retaincount)

Answer (score 3):

Don't trust the value of retain count. Especially as you are using ARC! Follow the rules. That's all.

Comment: +1 The implication is that you can't use retainCount with ARC.  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html

Comment: AFAIK, this wouldn't even compile under ARC; using `retainCount` throws an error.

Answer (score 3):

NSNumber returns singleton instances for certain numbers (I believe integers 1 to 12, or something).

You shouldn't ever rely on the value of `retainCount`. Any number of things could be happening throughout your code or framework code that can change the retain count.

Answer (score 1):

The return type of `retainCount` is `NSUInteger`; that's an *unsigned* integer. The [string format specifier](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) `%d` is for a *signed* integer.

Cocoa uses `NSUIntegerMax` to represent the retain counts of immortal objects -- objects which will never be released. For performance reasons, it caches and reuses `NSNumber` objects representing small integers -- this `NSNumber` that you've created is apparently one of those, and is immortal.

When you interpret the maximum unsigned integer value as if it were signed (under [two's complement arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)), it appears to be -1.

To see the "true" value, you should use the specifier `%lu`, as indicated by the chart I linked to above.

However, you generally [shouldn't rely on `retainCount` to give you any useful information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784084/calling-retaincount-considered-harmful). This [is documented](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000052-BBCDAAJI):

> Because any number of framework objects may have retained an object in order to hold references to it, while at the same time autorelease pools may be holding any number of deferred releases on an object, it is very unlikely that you can get useful information from this method.

as [beryllium already noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8340230/).