# calling retain, retainCount analyzing EXC_BAD_ACCESS with release

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, exc-bad-access

I'm a java programmer new to Objective C, so please be gentle :)

I'getting an errorr message saying `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on calling release on an object:
I read documentation and threads on this site, but I see data that's confusing me

```
- (void) dealloc {
    NSLog(@"dealloc in image Retain count: %i", [image retainCount]);

  [image release];//method throwing EXC_BAD_ACCESS
  ..............
}
```

the logged retain count is: 1

In the code that is causing the dealloc I have:

```
UIImage *scrn = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:newImage];
NSLog(@"in after instantiation Retain count: %i", [scrn retainCount]);// logs retain count of 1
CGImageRelease(newImage);
Decoder *d = [[Decoder alloc] init];
.....
NSLog(@"in before decoding Retain count: %i", [scrn retainCount]);// logs retain count of 1
decoding = [d decodeImage:scrn cropRect:cropRect] == YES ? NO : YES;
NSLog(@"in after decoding Retain count: %i", [scrn retainCount]); // logs retain count of 2
[d release]; // this line causes invocation of dealloc on the previous code sniplet
[scrn release];
```

In decodeImage the following is going on:

```
- (BOOL) decodeImage:(UIImage *)i cropRect:(CGRect)cr {
NSLog(@"Decoder.mm.decodeImage initial Retain count i : %i retaincount image %i", [i retainCount], [image retainCount]); //logs: Decoder.mm.decodeImage initial Retain count i : 1 retaincount image 0
[self setImage: i];
NSLog(@"Decoder.mm.decodeImage after setting image Retain count i : %i retaincount image %i", [i retainCount], [image retainCount]);//logs: Decoder.mm.decodeImage after setting image Retain count i : 2 retaincount image 2

.......
return [self decode];
}
```

There are several things puzzeling me:

1. From what understood the retainCount is increased by calling retain or by instantiating a new object, not by assigningment of one var to another as is done  in self setImage: i]; however i see that the retaincount is increased by one
2. Before calling [d release] the logged retainCount is 2, in the method dealloc the count is 1
3. If the count is 1, why do I get the EXC_BAD_ACCESS ???

Edit: added additional code as requested

```
@implementation Decoder

@synthesize image;
```

The setting of image is mentioned in the third code sniplet above.

Comment: Show us the declaration of class Decoder (especially the part where image is defined).

Comment: retainCount is utterly useless;  don't call it.

Answer (score 3):

Retain count can also be incremented by the system (for build-in types) and by properties that are defined with the `retain` or `copy` attributes.  You're only responsible for the ones you cause (not the system retains), but don't depend on the retain count when trying to determine why you're getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS.  XCode has some good build-in analysis tools that are better for tracking down access errors.

One important thing to note: your retaincount will never go below 1 even if you release when the count is 1.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784084/calling-retaincount-considered-harmful) question for good information on retaincount.