# NSMutableArray addobject reference count +2?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

After add a object to `NSMutableArray` got reference count +2 ?

```
E2post *post = [E2post new];
[postsObjectArray addObject:post]
NSLog(@"RC post = %ld",CFGetRetainCount((__bridge CFTypeRef)(postsObjectArray[0])));
```

Comment: NSLog show: RC post = 3

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784084/calling-retaincount-considered-harmful

Comment: Do you have any problem with that? It's system information, how I know apple do not recommend to use it property. By the way I have different behavior, NSLog show RC post = 2.

Comment: The retain count is useless (which is why -retainCount was removed in ARC).   CGGetRetainCount doesn't make it any more useful.

Comment: The absolute retain count at any given moment is not really useful information. However, in this case I believe it is because ARC is retaining the object before it's passed in to `CFGetRetainCount()`. But perhaps bbum will correct me.