# iOS ARC _objc_rootRetainCount

Tags: objective-c, macos, automatic-ref-counting, retaincount

Xcode8, Mac OS 10.12. ARC

I created a MacOS Command Line Tool Project.

And here is the `main` function

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
            id array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            NSLog(@"array count is %lu", _objc_rootRetainCount(array));
            _objc_autoreleasePoolPrint();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And the result is as expected:

the retainCount of array is 1, and array doesn't register to autorelease pool.

But When I use `id array = [NSMutableArray array]` . The result changed, and it was not as expected.

The retainCount of array is 2, and array registered to autorelease pool.

It looks like these two functions (`objc_retainAutoreleaseReturnValue` and `objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue`) didn't work.

---

Now I create an iOS APP. And here is the code in viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // id __weak tmp = nil;
    id array = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSLog(@"%lu", _objc_rootRetainCount(array));
}
```

The retainCount of array is 1.

But if I uncommented the line `id __weak tmp = nil;`, the result changed to 2. Very strange..

Comment: Convenience initializers return an autoreleased object, so you have the retain count from `alloc init` plus the one ARC adds to make sure the array lives until it's last reference in the code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784084/calling-retaincount-considered-harmful

Comment: @Cristik I think when I use `id array = [NSMutableArray array]` the return object should not be an autoreleased object. Because the `objc_retainAutoreleaseReturnValue` and `objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue `

Comment: @vanney, `[NSMutableArray array]` is a shorthand for `[[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease]` - event though the `autorelease` is no longer available.

Comment: @Cristik Not necessarily.  Under ARC, the compiler and runtime collude to avoid dropping objects in the autorelease pool.   All of which are implementation details and, ultimately, **retainCount is utterly and completely useless.**

Comment: @bbum did you mean that the array object didn't register to the autorelease pool and the `_objc_rootRetainCount` didn't return the correct retainCount?

Comment: @vanney The retain count is as correct as it'll ever be.  It'll change depending on compiler settings, targeted platform, software version, and/or presence/absence of other code.  So, to repeat, **the retainCount is useless** .http://www.friday.com/bbum/2011/12/18/retaincount-is-useless/