# Is retainCount giving me the correct information for my NSDate?

Tags: ios, memory, properties, nsdate, retaincount

I have NSDate property

In .h

```
...
@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
...
      NSDate *pageStartDate;
...
}
...
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *pageStartDate;
...
```

In .m

```
...
-(void)myMethod
{
   ...
   // set date of start showing page
   NSDate *tempStartDate = [NSDate date];
   [tempStartDate retain];
   pageStartDate = tempStartDate;
   [tempStartDate release];
   ...
}
...
```

After running this code the `[tempStartDate retainCount]` = 1 - is it normal?
If I write `self.pageStartDate = tempStartDate` than `[pageStartDate retainCount]` = 2.

Is there right use of NSDate, or not is?

Comment: If you write @syncronize pageStartDate; it mean that retain count 1 is normal

Comment: I wrote @synchronize, of course. I'm needed in property 'pageStartDate', but when I use `self.pageStarDate` this retainCount increases to 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't just your `NSDate` its because you've used [`retainCount`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636146/when-to-use-retaincount/4636157#4636157)

Annotation:

```
NSDate *tempStartDate = [NSDate date]; // No alloc, retain, copy, or mutableCopy - so assume autoreleased instance
[tempStartDate retain]; // You call retain - you own this now
pageStartDate = tempStartDate; // Not going through the setter. :(
[tempStartDate release];  // You've released this correctly, except for the step above.
                          // pageStartDate is now pointing to a garbage pointer.
```

You've done the right thing by releasing what you've retained, but pageStartDate didn't hold on to the value.

Try this

```
self.pageStartDate = [NSDate date];
```

Since you are using `retain` for the pageStartDate property, this will retain the value for you.

But - trying to use `retainCount` to check your memory management is, basically, doing it wrong.

Comment: In which case accepting my answer and/or upvoting is the usual way of thanking someone on SO.

Comment: But I think about this: `self.pageStartDate = [NSDate date];
    NSLog(@"[pageStartDate retainCount] = %i", [pageStartDate retainCount]);` In Log I see `[pageStartDate retainCount] = 2` - is it normal? Because I have ONE `release` of `pageStarDate` in my code - in `-(void)dealloc`

Comment: DON'T USE `retainCount`. It tells you nothing about running code. See the link in my answer. Just worry about the memory management rules and don't look at what `retainCount` tells you. Remember - the date value is `autoreleased` - which means it will be released when the autorelease pool drains which may no be immediately.

Comment: Oups, I didn't catch link in your answer. Thank again!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't write `self.pageStartDate` it won't use the property, so yes, the retain count of 1 is expected. Also, note that this instance is autoreleased (because you created it with [NSDate date]), so it will be released later.

If you were using the property, you wouldn't need the `retain` and `release` statements.