# Objective-C - pointer not nil after destroying the object

Tags: objective-c, pointers, object, null

I'm playing a little on my linux with Objective-C. Actually I'm trying to learn it, and while working on this quest, I got stuck.

Here is the code:

```
#import <stdio.h>
#import <Foundation/NSObject.h>


int main(void) {

    NSObject *a = [[NSObject alloc] init];

    printf("Class retain count: %i\n", [a retainCount]);
    printf("Is pointer nil: %i\n\n", (a==nil));

    [a retain]; 

    printf("Class retain count: %i\n", [a retainCount]);
    printf("Is pointer nil: %i\n\n", (a==nil));

    [a release];

    printf("Class retain count: %i\n", [a retainCount]);
    printf("Is pointer nil: %i\n\n", (a==nil));

    [a release];

    //printf("Class retain count:   %i\n", [a retainCount]);
    printf("Is pointer nil: %i\n", (a==nil));


    return 0;
}
```

And this is the output:

*Class retain count: 1*

Is pointer nil: 0

Class retain count: 2

Is pointer nil: 0

Class retain count: 1

Is pointer nil: 0

Is pointer nil: 0

I've commented out last printf because it crashes the program (I get "Segmentation fault      obj/test" 'cause a isn't set to nil ...). So what am I doing wrong ? Why isn't pointer set to nil ? It just keeps it's old value (before object is deleted) ...

Comment: **retainCount** is useless.  Don't call it.

Comment: @bbum: Could you please explain why ?

Comment: The retain count of an object is an internal implementation detail that is often meaningless (try `[@"foo" retainCount]`).  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636146/when-to-use-retaincount

Comment: Since it is 2014, you should be using ARC, which completely changes things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

releasing the object will not set it to nil. `release` will release the object that is pointed by your variable (in this case `a`) however you variable still pointing to the same object memory address unless you do assign another address like:

```
a = otherAddress;
```

usually you will do:

```
a = nil; //or
a = [[NSObject alloc] init]; //or
a = [MyObject objectWithSomething:smthg];
```

So, if you plan to reuse `a` after its deallocated then set it to nil after you finished. To avoid "Segmentation fault" errors if by any chance you attempt to use `a` and it is pointing to a deallocated object.

Comment: Well, you'll get a fault when you reuse `a` after it is _deallocated_, not necessary after it's released.

Comment: @Jonathan Sterling: Well, you'll get a fault when you reuse `a` after it is deallocated *and the memory is used for something else*, not necessarily after it's deallocated and reused.

Comment: thanks, I don't know why I thought that it would be set to nil automatically :D

Answer (score 3):

> Why isn't pointer set to nil ?

Because pointers to Objective-C objects are just pointers. When you `free` memory in plain C, you wouldn't expect your pointers to be set to NULL.

Answer (score 2):

A pointer doesn't become `nil` unless you assign `nil` to it. That the pointer is invalid does *not* mean that it will be `nil`. You have to consider a pointer just like any arbitrary integer: if you set it to some number, it will continue having that value until you set it otherwise.

That's why you can't use `obj == nil` to check whether an object is still valid.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to explicitly `set the variable` `nil` after releasing it.

```
[a release];
//This below line say : i don't have need to use the variable anymore. 
a = nil ;
```

if you don't have any use of a **variable** then first `release` and set that with `nil` value. (Setting `nil` is necessary).