# check retain count

Tags: iphone, xcode4, dealloc, retaincount

I am doing this :

```
UIImageView *backgroundImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mainback.jpg"]];

[self.view addSubview:backgroundImage];
NSLog(@" retain count1 : %d " , [backgroundImage retainCount]);
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:backgroundImage];

[backgroundImage release];
NSLog(@" retain count2 : %d " , [backgroundImage retainCount]);
```

I got

```
retain count1 : 2 
retain count2 : 1
```

1 ) in dealoc function can i get message like :

```
- (void)dealloc{

NSLog(@" retain count2 : %d " , [backgroundImage retainCount]);
[super dealloc];
}
```

And 2) at last i got retain count **1** for **backgroundimage** so it is ok or it should be **0(zero)**??

Thanks..

Comment: No, you should never use it.

Saves me explaining it check [this out][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636146/when-to-use-retaincount

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/retainCount),

> The retainCount method does not account for any pending autorelease
>   messages sent to the receiver.
>
> Important: **This method is typically of no value in debugging memory
>   management issues**. Because any number of framework objects may have
>   retained an object in order to hold references to it, while at the
>   same time autorelease pools may be holding any number of deferred
>   releases on an object, **it is very unlikely that you can get useful
>   information from this method**. To understand the fundamental rules of
>   memory management that you must abide by, read “Memory Management
>   Rules”. To diagnose memory management problems, use a suitable tool:
>   The LLVM/Clang Static analyzer can typically find memory management
>   problems even before you run your program. The Object Alloc instrument
>   in the Instruments application (see Instruments User Guide) can track
>   object allocation and destruction. Shark (see Shark User Guide) also
>   profiles memory allocations (amongst numerous other aspects of your
>   program).