# Instruments says I'm leaking a string, but I can't find it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory, memory-leaks

I used the leaks tool in Instruments to test the code, but the leaks tool cannot seem to find the leak.

At the end of my code, the output of `NSLog(@"str count:%d",[str retainCount]);` is 3. Why? I don't override  the dealloc. [a.name retainCount] is there just one time
and I only autorelease str for one time. So str shouldn't leak.

```
@interface DataMode : NSObject {

    NSString * name;
}

@property (retain) NSString * name;

- initWithName:(NSString * )name_;
@end


@implementation DataMode

@synthesize name;

- initWithName:(NSString * )name_
{
    if ([super init] != nil)
    {
        name = name_;
        return self;
    }
    return nil;
}

@end


- (void) pressed:(id)sender
{
    for( int i = 0;i<10000000;i++)
    {
        NSString * str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"zhang"];
        DataMode * a = [[DataMode alloc] initWithName:str];
        NSLog(@"a0 count:%d",[a retainCount]);
        NSLog(@"name1 count:%d",[a.name retainCount]);
        NSLog(@"name1 count:%d",[a.name retainCount]);
        NSLog(@"a1 count:%d",[a retainCount]);
        [ a  release];
        NSLog(@"str count:%d",[str retainCount]);
        NSLog(@"str count:%d",[str retainCount]);
    }


}
@end
```

Comment: What troubles were you having in posting a question? Maybe we can help.

Comment: Also, calling `-retainCount` is discouraged, and is particularly useless on NSStrings. I'm sure someone will be along presently to elucidate.

Comment: As a side note, you should copy or at least retain the string object you are assigning to the `name` ivar in your initializer method.

Comment: Are you using ARC? Garbage collection? Manual memory management?

Comment: retainCount wouldn't compile in ARC and `retainCount` effectively returns `self` in GC.... gotta be manual.

Comment: i  think it  should have leaks

Comment: i  think it  should have leaks.  because [a.name retainCount] add 1 ,But I dont't release it.  thus   I don't use ARC.

Answer (score 3):

## retainCount is useless.  Don't call it.

It is not useful for finding leaks as there are much better, more accurate, and less misleading tools available.

There are several problems with your code (but leaking isn't one of them):

- NSString* properties should be `copy`
- you don't use the property to set the string value in `init`, thus the DataMode instances are not retaining their strings.
- there is no dealloc method

<s>As for the retain counts; I'm surprised it is "3".   I'd expect it to be 2bazillionsomething as that is a constant string (and `stringWithString:` of a constant string just returns the string).</s>Since you used `stringWithFormat:`, the constant string is turned into a non-constant string.   If you had used the constant string or `stringWithString:`, it'd be abazillionsomething (unsigned -1... UINT_MAX...).

In any case, you have:

- +1 for `stringWithString:`
- +1 for calling `a.name`
- +1 for calling `a.name`

+3 overall.

If Instruments is claiming a leak, post a screenshot.

Comment: It’s not a constant string because the OP used `+stringWithFormat:`… and without a format, heh.

Comment: Oh, derp.  Right.  `stringWithString:` does that.  `stringWithFormat:` doesn't bother (though it could).

Comment: i  think it  should have leaks. tools can't find it. because [a.name retainCount] add 1 ,But I dont't release it.  thus   I don't use ARC.

Comment: i  think it  should have leaks. tools can't find it. because [a.name retainCount] add 1 ,But I dont't release it.The count of str is 3. I only autorelease it a time.  thus   I don't use ARC.

Answer (score 0):

I quote the [NSObject protocol reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html) for `-retainCount`:

> This method is typically of no value in debugging memory management issues. Because any number of framework objects may have retained an object in order to hold references to it, while at the same time autorelease pools may be holding any number of deferred releases on an object, it is very unlikely that you can get useful information from this method.

The retain count could be 3 for any number of reasons; if you can't find a leak with the leaks tool, it's likely you don't have a leak. Don't worry about the actual value of the retain count.

If you're *really* interested in why it's 3, recall that:

- The reference from your DataMode object `a` will likely be held until the closest autorelease pool is drained
- You're still holding a reference in the `str` variable
- The NSString class cluster, among others, does some - unusually inexplicable - caching things internally, so you may see a few retains here and there for which nobody can account

Comment: almost right on where the retains are coming from....   The DataMode object's presence in an autorelease pool wouldn't affect the retain count of the string.

Comment: The code is confusing;  DataMode isn't retaining the string ever given the way the rest of the code is written.  It is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the convenience method to create `str` which is autoreleased you will not see determinate behavior using retain counts in this way.

Check my response to another question and add those methods to `DataMode` and you should see when the framework releases your objects from the autorelease pool.

[Overriding release and retain in your class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491095/how-to-find-the-reference-count-of-an-object/7492117#7492117)