# Retain / Release - Reference Count

Tags: ios, ios4

Please kindly point out what is wrong in my code. I define a variable idleTimer of my custom type

@property (nonatomic, retain)           IdleTimer               *idleTimer;

Then when I run the following codes, it crashes.

```
IdleTimer   *idleTimerTemp  =   [[IdleTimer alloc] initTimer:PERIOD_COUPON_POPUP];
idleTimer   = idleTimerTemp;

NSLog(@"Pt. 1 %d %d", [idleTimerTemp retainCount], [idleTimer retainCount]);

[idleTimer setDelegate:self];
[idleTimerTemp release];
NSLog(@"Pt. 2 %d %d", [idleTimerTemp retainCount], [idleTimer retainCount]);
```

If the idleTimer is used again, it crashes.

But it I retain the idleTimerTemp on "idleTimer = idleTimerTemp". No crash at all.

But my variable is defined as retain. what is wrong ?

Comment: I am using XCODE 4.2 with iOS 5

Comment: As a side note, [-retainCount is not all that useful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636146/when-to-use-retaincount/4636477#4636477).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your property is defined as `retain` but that doesn't do anything with respect to the instance variable which is the backing storage for the property. Presumably somewhere in your code, you've done an `@synthesize idleTimer;`. That creates an accessor pair which implements the memory management you requested.

The only way to get that behavior is to call the accessor itself. So if you assign directly to `idleTimer`, that does nothing, but if you use `self.idleTimer = idleTimerTemp`, then the `-setIdleTimer:` accessor gets called, which will retain the parameter.

Comment: So, is it a correct approach that I don't call [idleTimerTemp release] in this case ? Is it a common practice ?

Comment: In this case, you'd probably release `idleTimer` in your class's `-dealloc` method.

Answer (score 2):

You're assigning to the `idleTimer` ivar directly instead of using the accessors. Do this instead:

```
self.idleTimer = idleTimerTemp;
```

The property accessors can't implement the semantics you specify if you don't use them.

Comment: Think about it this way: `self.idletimer=X` is shorthand for `[self setIdleTimer:X]` (with type checking).