# Am I getting memory leak ?

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, ios4

I've created UITabBarController programmatically, like this

```
mTabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
...
NSLog(@"The ref count is : %d", [tabBarItems retainCount]);
mTabBarController.viewControllers = tabBarItems;
NSLog(@"The ref count is : %d", [tabBarItems retainCount]);
[tabBarItems release];
NSLog(@"The ref count is : %d", [tabBarItems retainCount]);
```

Also releasing mTabBarController in dealloc, like this,

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [mTabBarController release];
    ...
}
```

Now the question : The output for the first code snippet is

```
2011-11-01 17:48:26.554 PostCardPrinter[12176:207] The ref count is : 1
2011-11-01 17:48:26.561 PostCardPrinter[12176:207] The ref count is : 1
2011-11-01 17:48:26.561 PostCardPrinter[12176:207] The ref count is : 1
```

Am I getting memory leak ? And why it prints 1 always ?

if it retains tabBarItems then the second output should be 2. If

```
mTabBarController.viewControllers = tabBarItems;
```

copies array items and retains each each array item then, the 3rd output should b 2 right ?

Do I get something wrong ???

Comment: Let the retainCount rant begin! -Edit: found it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636146/when-to-use-retaincount

Comment: OK, since I'm new t iOS dev, I really need that your comment ;) btw you better write an answer than comment ...

Comment: @Joe I was looking forward to more of a rant than that. I was the only participant!

Comment: @JamesWebster I am thinking most people are just over it by now :) Apple really should not have exposed it as a public API at least with ARC it is now illegal to call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retain count bad: [When to use -retainCount?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636146/when-to-use-retaincount)

In short: You can't guarantee `retainCount` will return a sensible value.