# -[__NSArrayM text]: called without reason

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, unrecognized-selector

I have a calendar with events inside, and I want the user to be able to add notes to every event. I do this through a UITextView, but the app crashes some times after writing the first letter saying

> -[__NSArrayM text]: Unrecognized selector sent to instance

The weird part is, that I use no code whatsoever to track the input, until the user hits a "Done" button. I get the same error when using UITextField as well, and I can't find out why does the error sometimes occur, and sometimes it works all fine.

Comment: Well, `NSArray` doesn't have a `text` method.  What does the backtrace say?

Comment: It isn't called without reason, it's called because somewhere you have passed the wrong object or over released an object (so another object is receiving a method call not intended for it). You need to find out which and where.

Comment: Well the thing is that I am not calling it. As for the error, I don't have it here with me as it occurs only from time to time and I just can't get to reproduce it right now, but it is pretty much only that piece of code I put in my question

Comment: > -[__NSArrayM text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xaba93d0

Comment: > *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xaba93d0'

Comment: Consider turning on zombies: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190227/how-do-i-set-up-nszombieenabled-in-xcode-4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a dangling reference.  You had an object that responded to the `text` message.  You deallocated it but you still have a reference to it somewhere.  You reused the memory of that deallocated object to create an `NSMutableArray`, then sent the `text` message through the dangling reference.

Run your app under the Zombies instrument to help track down the bug.

Comment: zombies will give you the class... you may also have to go through the whole malloc logging rigmarole to see what the whole story is.

Comment: Instruments takes care of malloc logging for you.  [It can show you the call stacks of every `retain`, `release`, and `autorelease` message, and the call stacks of the object's `alloc` and `dealloc`.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14891837/77567)