# In ARC, why is self in init methods a consumed parameter?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I want to understand ARC, and I'm reading this:

> http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#consumed-parameters

It says that a *consumed* parameter is retained before the call, and released at the end of the function (inside the function body). It then says that `init...` methods are effectively marked with `ns_consumes_self`. I don't see the point.

```
Foo *foo = [[Foo alloc] initWithWhatever: x];
```

So `alloc` returns an object with a retain count of 1, right? Now it is retained *again* before going into `init`, and then released at the end of `init`, so we're back at 1. Why is it designed like this?  When I think about what the typical `init` looks like, I get more confused.

```
self = [super init];
if (self) { ... } 
return self;
```

Comment: This remark from the Clang documentation might also be interesting: *"Typically, local optimization will remove any extra retains and releases: on the caller side the retain will be merged with a +1 source, and on the callee side the release will be rolled into the initialization of the parameter."*

Comment: @MartinR Yep.  's the reason we don't have to `autorelease` before assignment anymore.

Answer (score 8):

> So alloc returns an object with a retain count of 1, right? Now it is
>   retained again before going into init, and then released at the end of
>   init, so we're back at 1. Why is it designed like this?

Probably because initializers are free to return a pointer to a different object than the one that `self` points to initially. An `-init` method can say: *I don't like this object, I think I'll substitute a different one* and that's perfectly OK. Before ARC, such an initializer would explicitly release `self` (even though it never retained it) and then assign some other pointer to it. Presumably, the `ns_consumes_self` directive will take care of releasing the object that was passed into the initializer even if `self` is changed to point to some other object inside the method.

> When I think about what the typical init looks like, I get more confused.

It's a good bet that the behavior is there to cover cases that don't look like a *typical* `-init` method. Modifying `self` isn't exactly typical, it's just permissible.

Answer (score 4):

Why shouldn't it be that way?  Calls to `-init` are meant to return a given object with a +1 retain count, and doing a "temporary retain" is the safest way of guaranteeing that self remains alive throughout the entirety of a given init method.  Consider what happens if we peel back the layer of Objective-C abstraction and turn `-init` into the function pointer it's IMP resolves to:

```
id init(id self, SEL _cmd) {
    //+0 self given requires explicit retain to guarantee lifetime
    //...
    //(if retained) +1 self is returned; (if not retained) +0 self is deallocated
}
```

If given a `self` with a +0 retain count (as is common in most methods that retain their arguments i.e. setters), then you would have to guarantee that somewhere up the inheritance chain someone was nice enough to retain self away from whatever happened to allocate it (ending in `self` having a rather ambiguous retain count of +1).  But, if you receive a self with a +1 retain count, and you do a retain-release it yourself,you can be certain that it remains alive through your `-init` method, and that you and you alone have ownership of `self`.  And if the given self was not "alive", then you're guaranteed to return nil rather than an object in the middle of deallocation.  Thus, the above becomes (in pseudo-C):

```
id init(__attribute((ns_consumed))id self, SEL _cmd) {
    //implicit retain of +1 self returns self with +2
    //...
    //implicit release of +2 self returns self with +1
}
```

I like to call this pattern "old-school atomic access", and it's used in Apple frameworks designed before `@synchronized {}` atomic getters were invented.  When you use a getter backed with a public iVar.  You'll often see methods that follow that pattern written like:

```
- (NSView *)view {
    //explicit retain-autorelease of +1 variable is +2 -> +1, guaranteed access or nil.
    return [[_view retain]autorelease];
}
```

But all of this doesn't touch the ownership rules of the exception that is `-init` and family.  `-init` methods return objects +1, but who exactly owns them?  Well, the allocator* still has a hand in the reference to the variable, and `self = [super init]` [doesn't actually retain anything](https://github.com/opensource-apple/objc4/blob/master/runtime/NSObject.mm#L1772) (and it also has to obey the whole "returns +1" rule).  Well, again I have to turn to pseudo-code, but this time it'll be in Objective-C:

```
- (id)init {
    //self is +1 because -init must return +1
    self = [super init];
    //implicit [self retain]; leaves self with a +2 reference count
    //...
    //implicit [self autorelease]; leaves self with a +1 reference count
    return self;
}
```

OK, so now you've got a +1 object floating around claimed by the allocator, so how do *you* "claim" it?  Assignment, of course!  The point of implicitly `__strong` locals and `__strong` properties is to reclaim the object from the allocator entity.

```
- (void)f {
    //Freestanding +1 variable is not owned by the caller, will be deallocated when the method
    //passes out of scope.
    [[NSObject alloc]init];

    //Implicitly __strong local captures reference away from allocator entity, 
    //which "autoreleases" it's ownership
    //We now "own" the returned object.
    NSObject *obj = [[NSObject alloc]init];

    //Strong property captures reference away from local, saves the object from being deallocated
    //when the method passes out of scope
    self.object = obj;
}
```

*<sub>Allocator, in the context of this answer, refers to the functions that eventually call `malloc()` to allocate space for the object.</sub>

Comment: Perhaps the confusion here comes from the fact that unless you're up on the ObjC runtime, it's not totally clear that `self` and `cmd` are implicit parameters.

Comment: Doesn't alloc return a +1 object already, which is passed to init? If you have to do a retain to "guarantee that self is valid" though the method, why don't we have to do that with every other normal instance method? I thought you could assume that the caller owns self and is not releasing it mid-method.

Comment: The Cocoa docs I see say exactly that -- you own objects created with alloc/new/copy methods.

Comment: Is there a way to log or watch retain/release calls? With ARC on it won't let me override those methods. That might help me.

Comment: OK, that should be clearer.  You're misunderstanding the difference between reference count and ownership.  +alloc does return an object with a +1 reference count, but it is not owned by anyone or anything until assignment or retention occurs.

Comment: @RobN Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14891837/77567) for help tracing all retains and releases of an object.