# What is wrong with this init method that would cause memory issues? (iOS)

Tags: objective-c, memory, singleton

I'm trying to understand what is wrong with the following code.

Imagine the following class, "Foo":

```
@protocol FooDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)hereTakeThisFooBarDic:(NSDictionary *)fooBarDic;
@end

@interface Foo : NSObject <BarDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) Bar *bar;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <FooDelegate> *fooDelegate;
- (void)getFooBarDicForNum:(int)fooBarNum;
@end

@implementation Foo

static Foo *foo = nil;

- (id)init {
    if (!foo) {
        foo = [super init];
        self.bar = [[bar alloc] init];
    }
    return foo;
}

- (void)getFooBarDicForNum:(int)fooBarNum {
    self.bar.fooDelegate = self;
    [self.bar getFooBarDicFromIntarwebsNumber:fooBarNum];
}

//We get this callback from self.bar after a few ms
- (void)callbackWithFooBarDicFromIntarwebs:(NSDictionary *)fooBarDic {
    [self.fooDelegate hereTakeThisFooBarDic:fooBarDic];
}
@end
```

We call Foo from somewhere in code like this:

```
   for(int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
       Foo *foo = [[Foo alloc] init];
       [foo getFooBarDicForNum:i];
   }
```

Then we get the callbacks later in a `hereTakeThisFooBarDic` method.

But the problem is we are getting unbounded memory growth. It seems that Foo's `init` method acts like a singleton, but every time we call it we are allocating more memory for it. It does not register as a memory leak though. In looking at this code it does not seem like the right way to do a singleton, though.

I'd like to know what the authors of this code did wrong.

Comment: Never make a delegate property `strong`. It should be `weak`.

Comment: Sorry that was just a typo.

Comment: Never start a method name with `get` (unless it falls into one of the vary rare Objective-C conventions where it makes sense; this does not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ARC the `init` method you show should not leak, and at least with Xcode 7.2/Clang 7.0.2 does not leak (i.e. the compiler correctly implements the ARC semantics).

However the `init` method is not "correct" (ignoring any multithreading issues), even though it works in this case:

```
- (id)init {
    if (!foo) {
        foo = [super init];
```

The above line appears to *assume* that the value return by `[super init]` will be the same as `self` as in the next line...

```
        self.bar = [[bar alloc] init];
```

It assigns to `self` assuming this is the same value as in `foo`...

```
    }
    return foo;
```

And such assumptions are not only wrong, but this very `init` method is an example of one which may not return the `self` it was passed!

```
}
```

At least you didn't write it!

What the author should have written (if following this particular "shared instance" pattern) is something along the lines of:

```
- (id)init
{
   if (!foo)
   {
      self = [super init];
      self.bar = [[Bar alloc] init];
      foo = self;
      return self;
   }

   return foo;
}
```

That said, this is not the recommended shared instance pattern. If you are interested in that and how to make a modern singleton pattern there are plenty of references, I'll point you at [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30799696/singleton-in-ios-objective-c-doesnt-prevent-more-than-one-instance/30828622#30828622), can't think why ;-)

As to your suspected leak, it's not the `init` and does not appear to be the other two methods either, so you'll need to look at what those in turn call. Happy hunting!

HTH

Comment: Yeah the one you link to is how I always make my singletons. I wasn't sure if this other was was advisable.. and as you alluded, it certainly does not seem threadsafe. And yeah, the guys who wrote this? They were using it to receive the callbacks of NSURLSession... facepalm...

Comment: Further reading: ARC's behavior here is described by the ["ns_consumes_self"](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#consumed-parameters) annotation, implicitly applied to `init`. See also [In ARC, why is self in init methods a consumed parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17242328). @CommaToast

Comment: @JoshCaswell - exactly, though the referenced question I think misreads the semantics slightly - the point is ownership is transferred from caller to callee, a caller-side retain is only required if the caller doesn't already have ownership. I didn't write my answer though until I'd checked the current compiler was implementing these semantics correctly, just in case...

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call `[[Foo alloc] init]`, a new `Foo` is being created, but ignored. If you're not compiling with ARC, this is indeed a leak: you've allocated something and are not releasing it. If you are, it's still weird and I'm not sure it would surprise me if it was still a leak.

If you want a singleton that operates this way, you must allocate it only once, and ensure that subsequent calls to `+alloc` return that same instance. [Peter Hosey has a very interesting blog post](http://boredzo.org/blog/archives/2009-06-17/doing-it-wrong) about it.

Comment: Blog seems to be down at the moment, but the code is available for perusal: https://bitbucket.org/boredzo/singleton/src

Comment: The weird thing is that if I do: `Foo *foo1 = [[Foo alloc] init];` followed by `Foo *foo2 = [[Foo alloc] init];` then they return identical pointers (i.e. `foo1 == foo2` is true). So are you convinced that the alloc method is indeed leaking? Instruments doesn't report it as a leak... is it possible that a new memory page is being set aside and just never gets used for anything? Its very confusing.

Comment: Also that singleton link you sent me looks very pre-ARC. When I write singletons I use the dispatch method typically. But this code came from overseas...

Comment: They return identical pointers because `init` is returning `foo` every time. It gets assigned the first time `init` runs, and then returned after that. `alloc` is the method responsible for allocating memory for the new instance. That instance is passed into `init` (as `self`) and no other reference to it exists. It absolutely leaks without ARC.

Comment: Peter's code is easy enough to update to ARC, but  the standard `dispatch_once()` idiom is generally fine. I just pointed to the blog for further understanding.

Comment: But I'm using ARC, so would alloc still leak or cause unbounded memory growth in the above code?

Comment: I would not be astonished if it did. Are you seeing a leak?

Comment: Unbounded growth. But not sure from what exactly... as tends to be the case with unbounded growth if you know what i mean.