# Instruments profile to view the retain count of an object

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, memory-management

I have an app that use one `NSMutableArray` directly from the `delegate`. three different classes can access to them and manage the content. Sometimes I need to `removeAllItems` from the array and reload it with new elements... Unfortunately it seems that memory wasn't released... How can I trace the retain count of that objets using instruments? If I use the Leaks Profile I can't see any leek but what I want is that when I `removeallobjects` from the `NSMutableArray` the memory must be released...
Any suggestions? any tutorials?
thanks

Comment: That's not enough information to answer your question; please provide some examples of how the array is being manipulated.  Do you know what objects aren't being released?

Comment: Using the Allocations instrument can often help you. Enable the "track reference counts" option and it will list out every place your objects are retained/released etc. Can be hard to work through when the object is used in many places.

Comment: This answer might helps.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890402/instruments-allocations-track-alloc-and-dealloc-of-objects-of-user-defined-class