# Can i make an Xcode breakpoint when a certain class gets added to autorelease pool?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode5, autorelease

I'm trying to debug some ARC code, and it'd be really helpful if i could find out when an object of a certain class is added to the autorelease pool (*not* when it is actually autoreleased down the track).

Is this possible, eg with a breakpoint? Or by overwriting the 'autorelease' method and putting a breakpoint in it? Any suggestions?

-- edit --

The problem is that i've got an infrequent crash occurring where a custom subclass of UIView is autoreleased on a background thread, which crashes because UIView's cannot be dealloc'd on a background thread. The trace looks like below:

```
0    libsystem_kernel.dylib  __pthread_kill + 8
1    libsystem_c.dylib   pthread_kill + 54
2    libsystem_c.dylib   abort + 94
3    libc++abi.dylib     abort_message + 46
4    libc++abi.dylib     default_terminate() + 24
5    libobjc.A.dylib     _objc_terminate + 146
6    libc++abi.dylib     safe_handler_caller(void (*)()) + 76
7    libc++abi.dylib     operator delete(void*)
8    libc++abi.dylib     __cxa_throw + 122
9    libobjc.A.dylib     objc_exception_throw + 94
10   CoreFoundation  +[NSException raise:format:]
11   Foundation  -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 90
12   MYAPP   MySuperclass.m line 156 -[MySuperclass dealloc]
13   MYAPP  MyClass.m line 41 -[MyClass dealloc]
14 ...   libobjc.A.dylib     _objc_rootRelease + 36
15   libobjc.A.dylib     objc_release + 38
16   libobjc.A.dylib     (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 224
17   libobjc.A.dylib     _objc_autoreleasePoolPop + 12
18   CoreFoundation  _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 18
19   libdispatch.dylib   _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 338
20   libsystem_c.dylib   _pthread_wqthread + 294
```

Comment: Could you tell us more about the problem you're trying to debug?  Perhaps there's a better way.  Note that [you can use the Allocations instrument to examine the call stack of every `retain`, `release`, and `autorelease` message sent to every object, and you can filter by the class of interest.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14891837/77567)

Comment: Ok i'll add it to the question

Comment: I tried to use instruments, but the app crashes immediately when launching via instruments. The crash log says: `Dyld Error Message: Symbol not found: _objc_setProperty_atomic`

Comment: No worries, I got instruments working on a colleagues computer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This might not help with your problem, but I think it answers your original question:

You can add a symbolic breakpoint on `[NSObject autorelease]` and then set a condition to match your class. If your running on a device `$r0` should hold the pointer to the receiving object. You need to do some casting to make the condition work: `(BOOL)[(id)$r0 isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]` breaks whenever an `NSArray` is added to the autoreleasepool. Note that everything will be running very slow as the debugger has to break on every autorelease and check the condition.

[image: Add a symbolic breakpoint]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this looks great! Any idea what the register would be for the receiving object on the simulator?

Comment: `$rdi`, @Chris. Greg Parker has [a table with all the architectures](http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2013/09/12/objc_explain_So_you_crashed_in_objc_msgSend_iPhone_5s_Edition.html)

Comment: I think it might be $eax actually?

Comment: I get the following error in my console: `error: use of undeclared identifier '$rdi'`

Comment: If i change it to $eax, i get this: `Couldn't execute expression:
Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x5de589dc).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
[no Objective-C description available]
Stopped due to an error evaluating condition of breakpoint 9.4: "(BOOL)[(id)$eax isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]"
`

Comment: I didn't get it to work in the simulator. Maybe the [iOS Debugging Magic Tech Note](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2239/_index.html) helps.

Comment: On a 32-bit x86 architecture, it's `(BOOL)[((id*)$esp)[1] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]`.

Comment: Thanks rob. And once it breaks, to get access to it in the lldb console, this works: `po ((id*)$esp)[1]`

Comment: FWIW, this technique *does* work, but it's incredibly slow. I think using the instruments trace here might be more usable: `http://stackoverflow.com/a/14891837/77567`