# How we can check that certain object is released memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

As I start working in swift, I am curious in memory mgmt. As we all know that during any object creation or assignment of data into that object it takes memory. How can we check that a particular object has released the memory. I used xcode memory report to see memory status and fluctuations.

Here is a sample of images:

[image]

[image]

How can release memory if I already set nil into the objects.

Comment: Thanks for comment, However I also check allocations and leaks via instruments. Ok I will do as you mentioned....

Comment: *"How can we check that a particular object has released the memory"* and *"How can release memory if I already set nil into the objects"* are two different questions.

Comment: Yes, For both has only one aim to get release memory. The last line for justification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use instruments to track the lifecycle of an object than just Xcode because it gives you the allocation details at much higher level.

Check out the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/14891837/5133769. Though it was explained with old instruments it still works.

Answer (score 3):

Some objects are very small and it could be difficult to see in Memory profiling which one is released. This tool is helpful for finding memory leaks in an app. To check was some object released from memory or wasn't you can setup breakpoints or logs in `dealloc()` method for objective c and in `deinit()` method for swift.

Answer (score 2):

Using instruments checking for leaks or allocations is the recommended way.

You can also set breakpoints or add logs to the dealloc method.