# Instruments > Allocations not showing app classes/objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, instruments

In previous versions of Instruments I had no problem but now (v6.2) for some reason Allocations won't list any of my app's objects. I've tried Debug and Release Mode:

[image: Empty Allocations with filter]

Note, the filter "VC" should catch all the ViewControllers.  And without the filter...

[image: Allocations without filter]

Any ideas?

Comment: I started having the same exact issue at the same exact time, FWIW. After many hours of searching online, there doesn't seem to be an answer

Comment: I've filed bug #20274288. Not sure how to link to it...

Comment: You can't, at least directly from Apple :/ You can post it to openradar.me and link it if you feel like it

Comment: Checking openradar.me, somebody else posted one for this bug also: http://www.openradar.me/20665225

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I tested this out with both 6.2 and 6.3 and encountered the issue. Also I was using the iOS 8.2 and 8.3 simulators. However, when I switched to the iOS 8.1 simulator, it worked properly. So it's not so much a bug with Instruments as it is an iOS bug, it appears, or at the very least a combination of the two.

So a workaround for now is to test Allocations using iOS 8.1 or earlier.

Comment: Had a similar problem where I was not seeing any references from Heapshot (all I would see was Malloc from swift_slowAlloc) - moving to an 8.1 simulator let me see data again!

Comment: Same here - get all my objects logged when I reverted to 8.1 to profile

Comment: This is still an issue on XCode 6.4 and iOS 8.4 ... the solution of using iOS 8.1 is still viable and worked first time. Thanks I thought I was going crazy when I ran into the issue!

Comment: Note: This is fixed in iOS9.0 it seems. I was having this problem with the 8.4 simulator, but on XCode 7+iOS9 it works