# Does a reference remain weak if passed as an argument in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, memory, memory-management, weak-references

When I pass self as an argument to a function, does it make any difference if I weakify it first?

For example:

```
__weak __typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
[self.someObject doWorkWithDelegate: weakSelf];
```

In the body of the doWork function it assigns it to a strong property

```
@property (strong) Foo* fooDelegate;
```

(I know this is terrible, don't get sidetracked).

This will still be a strong reference and cause a memory cycle despite theh fact that I "weakified" the reference first, correct?

Bonus Question: How can I check this myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the variable `weakSelf` which is weak. That is, ARC does not emit a retain when a value is assigned to it, nor a release when it goes out of scope (or is assigned a different value).

Since the `fooDelegate` property is strong, assigning to it releases any old value it may have had and retains the newly-assigned value.

So, yes, that will be a strong reference. It's not clear from what you posted whether it will constitute a retain cycle. The name of the method suggests that the delegate will be cleared (thus released) after the work has been completed. In that case, it's not a problem. It would only be a problem if `self.someObject` maintained the strong reference until it itself was released and `self` maintained a strong reference to `someObject` until `self` was released.

Comment: Thanks that part of ARC logic was exactly what I was missing. Is there a convenient way to identify whether a reference is weak / strong whilst debugging? Or not really since all __weak does is increment the ARC reference count

Comment: Ignore the comment this answer gives a thorough explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863269/how-do-i-verify-reference-count-in-arc-mode

Answer (score 0):

An important aspect of the original question could be further clarified. "When I pass `self` as an argument to a function, does it make any difference if I weakify it first?"

Note that in the example code block:

```
__weak __typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
[self.someObject doWorkWithDelegate: weakSelf];
```

ARC will perform a retain on each of the objects passed, including the receiver (i.e. `self.someObject` and `weakSelf`), and then a release on each when complete, allowing weak objects to be safely used for the lifetime of the called method. So the answer would be no, it doesn't make a difference to make it weak first because it will be strong for the duration of the call.

If the weak variable was simply referenced within a code block callback from the method, then it will still be weak within that scope.

So this is a common pattern to use a `weakSelf` variable within a block callback to call another method, `foo`, which then can safely use `self` because it is no longer weak during that execution of `foo`. But if `self` goes away before the callback is executed, then `[weakSelf foo]` will simply never be called because `weakSelf` has gone nil.

```
__weak __typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
[self.someObject doWorkWithCallback:^{
  [weakSelf foo];
}];

- (void)foo
{
  // Safely use self here.
  [self doMoreWork];
}
```