# After Autorelease pool is drained, retain count of autorelease variable is still 1. Shouldn't be zero

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When to use -retainCount?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636146/when-to-use-retaincount)

I was trying to understand autorelease pools. I created a sample application as below:

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

NSString *releasePoolString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",@"ReleasePool autorelease variable"] autorelease];

NSLog(@"Retain count of autorelease variable inside release pool %i",[releasePoolString retainCount]);

[pool drain];

// After pool drain still retain count = 1 ??????
NSLog(@"Retain count of autorelease variable after release pool drain %i",[releasePoolString retainCount]);
```

The last log still prints retaincount as 1.
Am I missing something ... can someone please help me understand ....

Thanks...

Comment: http://whentouseretaincount.com

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use ARC. It's now the default and is recommended for practically everyone.

Answer (score 4):

retainCount never reaches 0 because when it's 1 and release is called, it calls immediately dealloc without decrement retainCount

Answer (score 0):

Because the retainCount wont give exact retain count of an object always. You should not depend on `retainCount` API for memory management. Once you alloc, retain an object, you have to release that object and its retain count will become zero.