# Unexpected retainCount

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, retaincount

Have a look at this code-snippet with a simple retain/release scenario:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SomeClass : NSObject
@end

@implementation SomeClass
@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    SomeClass *aClass = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"retainCount: %lu", [aClass retainCount]);

    [aClass retain];
    NSLog(@"retainCount: %lu", [aClass retainCount]);

    [aClass release];
    NSLog(@"retainCount: %lu", [aClass retainCount]);

    [aClass release];
    NSLog(@"retainCount: %lu", [aClass retainCount]);

    return 0;
}
```

That's the resulting output:

```
2013-04-29 17:33:50.695 retainCount: 1
2013-04-29 17:33:50.697 retainCount: 2
2013-04-29 17:33:50.697 retainCount: 1
2013-04-29 17:33:50.698 retainCount: 1
```

The last retainCount should either be "0" or the app should crash. Why is the result "1" ?!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636146/when-to-use-retaincount?rq=1

Comment: **Never use `retainCount` for anything**

Comment: `retainCount` means nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.whentouseretaincount.com

Messaging a deallocated object is **undefined behavior**.   It might crash, it might work, it might do something completely unexpected.

Upon deallocation, your program won't waste any cycles mucking with the freshly deallocated memory (unless you turn on *malloc scribble*), thus the undefined part of the behavior.

Nor will your program waste any cycles decrementing the retain count to 0;  the object is going to be deallocated anyway, why bother?