# Why ARC autoreleased return value is nil?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

i'm using TMQuiltView, my project has ARC enabled, but TMQuilView does not. 
In my controller I dequeue the cell by

```
// ARC
TMQuiltViewCell* quiltCell = [_quiltView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
```

but `quiltCell` is always `nil`. Inside `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:` it likes this

```
// No ARC
- (TMQuiltViewCell *)dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier {
    TMQuiltViewCell *view = [[self reusableViewsWithReuseIdentifier:identifier] anyObject];
    if (view) {
        [view retain];            
        view.selected = NO;
        [[self reusableViewsWithReuseIdentifier:identifier] removeObject:view];
    }
    return [view autorelease];
}
```

The view is NOT nil, and alway has retain count is 1 before the `autorelease` call, but the returned value `quiltCell` is nil. Is that `[view autorelease]` releases `view` before returning? How do i keep reference to the returned object?

UPDATED:

I came up with a workaround by delay autorelease call a bit

```
[view performSelector:@selector(autorelease) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.01];
```

It works for me, but I still want to have a prettier solution.

Comment: I saw that the TMQuiltView was using retain count, but I dismissed that as I gather that's not your code. However, it looks like you're using that information to make judgements about whether or not it's working.. *don't*!. retain count is notoriously unreliable.

Comment: all the retaincount code i made to log the retain count to console, it  is not TMQuiltView original code. I removed all the loggin code.

Comment: Did you allocate any "TMQuiltViewCell" in the memory before using "dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier"?

Comment: no, i check if there is any reusable cell (returned object of `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:`) first, and allocate new `TMQuiltViewCell` only if I get nil. Pretty much the same way we usually do with UITableView

Comment: `all the retaincount code i made` - Then definitely don't! [Check out this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636146/when-to-use-retaincount)

Comment: thanks, those code is just for testing, it will never appear in my release, and it's not the main point of the question anyway.

Comment: `retainCount` isn't suitable for testing! It is the main point of the question if you're making deductions from that code.