# Changes to reference counting in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, reference-counting

I'm currently working on fixing some iOS 7 display issues on a legacy app which was not built with ARC, and have run into some inconsistent behaviour with the `dealloc` method between iOS versions 6 & 7. I can't find any other mention of these changes in any documentation or community discussions, so I wonder if anyone here could shed some light on what's happening here?

My previous code, (which works in iOS6, looks like this):

```
@interface MyViewController()
@property (retain) AdHandler *adHandler;
@end

@implementation MyViewController

@synthesize adHandler = _adHandler;

- (id) initWithAdHandler:(AdHandler*)anAdHandler
{
    self = [super init];
    _adHandler = [anAdHandler retain];
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{    
    [super dealloc];

    [_adHandler release];
    _adHandler = nil;
}

...

@end
```

When stepping through the code in iOS 6, I've found that after the `dealloc` statement, `[_adHandler retainCount]` is still positive, and the object is still available.

In iOS 7 however, after the `dealloc` statement, `retainCount` has somehow hit zero, and the `_adHandler` object has been `dealloc`'d, and therefore my call to `release` causes an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

I can fix this simply by moving my `[adHandler release]` call to before the `dealloc` call, but my question is why is this happening? Why is `dealloc` releasing objects that it has no responsibility for? Is there any documentation anywhere on why dealloc behaviour has changed in this way?

Comment: [**Never** use `retainCount`.](http://whentouseretaincount.com)

Comment: When you implement `-dealloc` in a non-ARC app, `[super dealloc]` should be the last statement, not the first.

Comment: If you use instruments, you can find out exactly where retain/release/autoreleases are happening on your objects

Comment: Your init method is incorrect, too.

Comment: @bbum could you explain?

Comment: @majackson You need to do `self = [super init]; if (self) { ... initialization junk } return self;`  Standard pattern.   And, as others have said, `retainCount` is completely useless, even for debugging.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After `[super dealloc]` the instance is garbage and whatever happens is rather random and non-deterministic. As @bneely wrote, `[super dealloc]` must be last.

Best practice: convert to ARC.

As for `retainCount`, there are no guarantees what it's value may be, don't use it, it just caused confusion. In your case you destroyed the class instance by calling `[super dealloc]` and then expect the instance to behave as if it still exists. It can't, it has been destroyed and is now just some non-deterministic bits in memory.

Comment: But after `dealloc`, `_adHandler` still contains a memory address, and the object in that memory address should not have had `release` called on it, so should still exist?

Comment: @majackson The memory can be already overwritten, especially in Debug mode

Comment: @Sulthan Why would the memory be overwritten if the retainCount has not hit zero? Potentially other objects could have references to that object!

Or do you mean the memory that contains the address to the object?

Comment: @majackson First bad assumption: That the retainCount will ever be zero. Second bad assumption: That a deallocated object can somehow be in a working state. Memory is released and reused, that is how these systems work.

Comment: @majackson When `super dealloc` has been called, the memory is returned to the system. It can be ovewritten immediately. If you call `self.something` later, the pointer you get is completely random (undefined). `retainCount` value is completely irrelevant because you cannot understand it without actually looking into Apple's source code.

Comment: @Sulthan This makes sense to me: the object in question hasn't (necessarily) been destroyed, but the pointer that was previously referencing it has been overwritten. Essentially, the answer to my question is that iOS7 is significantly more aggressive at overwriting this data than iOS6. If you'd posted an answer instead of a comment, that would be my accepted answer! Thanks.

Comment: @Zaph I think you misunderstood my previous comment. In any case, Sulthan has made the matter clearer in my mind. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @majackson I am pretty sure the code would trigger warnings already in Xcode 4. Note that in Debug mode the memory can be overwritten immediately for the purpose to trigger an exception if you access it again. Having code after `[super dealloc]` was always wrong and dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

[You should **never** use retain count.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636146/when-to-use-retaincount)

The values it returns cannot be interpreted by you in any reasonable way. Thus it's entirely expected to see different results on different iOS versions, devices, with different code bitness, etc.

---

On a side note, do you consider switching to ARC? The code would greatly simplify. Also note that if you're implementing a subclass of `UIViewController`, you shouldn't initialize it with `init`. Rather just declare the property and ARC will take care of its setters and getters:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
@property AdHandler *adHandler;
@end

// somewhere else 
MyViewController * mvc = ... from nib or in some other way ...
mvc.adHandler = myAdHandler;
```

Now you're guaranteed no bad accesses.

Comment: I'm using `retainCount` only for debugging purposes, not in production code.

Comment: And `retainCouut` is causing confusion! Don't use it.

Comment: As for ARC, I vastly prefer iOS development with it and do of course intend to migrate at some point, but there's currently not enough time scheduled to migrate this (rather large) app over to ARC.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: I agree, I kind of went sideways.