# ARC instance variable retain release

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

If we have .h file like this:

```
@interface TestViewController : UIViewController {

    __weak NSObject *object;
}

@end
```

and methods in .m file like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSObject *localObject = [[NSObject alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"%ld", CFGetRetainCount((__bridge CFTypeRef)localObject));
    object = localObject;
    NSLog(@"%ld", CFGetRetainCount((__bridge CFTypeRef)object));
    NSLog(@"%ld", CFGetRetainCount((__bridge CFTypeRef)localObject));
}
```

Then we get the following output for retain count:

1
2
1

My question is why does the retain count gets incremented to 2 on "object" when it is declared as "__weak" instance variable, furthermore "localObject" retain count remains 1.
I think that's because of how ARC inserts retain/release but I am not sure.

Comment: You might find an answer here: http://www.stackoverflow.com/a/4636477/1187415 as suggested by @Martin R

Comment: CFGetRetainCount() is identical to -retainCount in all ways, including being useless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all the usual disclaimer: the absolute value of the retain count does not tell you anything useful, for more information see

- http://whentouseretaincount.com
- [When to use -retainCount?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636146/when-to-use-retaincount)

Now in your case, in the line

```
NSLog(@"%ld", CFGetRetainCount((__bridge CFTypeRef)object));
```

you read the value of a weak pointer, and the [Clang/ARC documentation 4.2 Semantics](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#semantics) states about that:

> For `__weak` objects, the current pointee is retained and then released
>   at the end of the current full-expression.

Therefore the object's retain count is increased by one while passed to `CFGetRetainCount()`. You can see that also in the generated assembly code:

```
movq    %rbx, %rdi
callq   _objc_retain
movq    %rax, %rbx
.loc    1 21 0                  
movq    %rbx, %rdi
callq   _CFGetRetainCount
movq    %r15, %rdi
movq    %rax, %rsi
xorb    %al, %al
callq   _NSLog
movq    _objc_release@GOTPCREL(%rip), %r12
movq    %rbx, %rdi
callq   *%r12
```