# iOS retain count with ARC enable

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

Here is my code:

```
@interface YQViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *lb1;

@end

@implementation YQViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    self.title = @"title";

    self.lb1 = [[UILabel alloc]init];

    NSLog(@"retain count is %ld", CFGetRetainCount((__bridge CFTypeRef)self.lb1));

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@end
```

As you can see, I send `+alloc` and `-init` to `self.lb1`, I think the retain count of `self.lb1` should equal 1, but the console output is 2. Can someone tell me the reason.(ARC enable, xcode 5, OSX 10.9.1, iOS 7 simulator).

Comment: http://whentouseretaincount.com/

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking up the value of `retainCount`, you're doing it wrong. There's no exception to that. You cannot rely on the resulting value to reflect what's going on in your code.

For full details, see http://whentouseretaincount.com

Comment: Also covered in the accepted answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636146/when-to-use-retaincount/4636477#4636477