# Definition makes two references refer to the object in Swift

Tags: swift, object, memory-management

You can put the following code snippet into the Xcode playground

```
import CoreFoundation

class MyData {
    let someInt = 1
}
let a = MyData() //Definition of the varialbe a
print(CFGetRetainCount(a)) // it prints out 2
}
```

The only thing the code does is initialize an object of type `MyData` and assign it to a constant named **a**

I thought it would be only 1 reference (the constant **a**) "points to" the object, however, it turns out the object already has 2 references "point to" it.

**Question:**

1. Who is this second reference?
2. If the constant **a** is deallocated/destroyed then the object will not be deallocated because there is still a reference "points to" the object. (I guess my understanding is wrong, please point out any errors)

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't reproduce if you compile this code to an executable using `swiftc`, so it's most likely a playgrounds artifact.

Comment: Querying the retain count is almost always pointless: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636146/when-to-use-retaincount, http://sdarlington.github.io.

Comment: @MartinR Thx, good to know that

Comment: Looks like `a` gets passed as a guaranteed parameter, so caller retains the `MyData` instance before the call to `CFGetRetainCount` and releases after, hence why the retain count is reported as 2. In an optimised build, the compiler can eliminate that retain/release overhead (as it knows the instance is already +1 retained), therefore the retain count is reported as 1. And this is a perfect illustration of how, as Martin says, the querying the retain count of an instance is pointless :)